# How can I use more colors in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

There are only *white*, *black*, *red*, *green*, *blue*, *cyan*, *magenta*, and *yellow*. How can I add others? (I would like to use *Green* (different from *green*).)

Answer (score 16):

TikZ loads [`xcolor`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor), so you can use the coloring system of this package, which is very powerful.

For instance, you can use `green!20`, `green!30`, `green!40` etc., for different depths of green or even to mix it with other colors for ever more green colors. For example, `green!80!yellow!40`, `green!70!black!30`, etc. You can mix as many colors as you want.

Note the `!` symbol which separates colors and color depth. You can also define your own colors. For more information use the documentation of the [`xcolor`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf) package, as Ingmar mentioned in a previous comment.

Answer (score 9):

LaTeX can help you with an infinite combination of colors—not limited to only VIBGYOR primary. Just head on over to *[LaTeX Color Definitions](http://latexcolor.com)* and see the endless possibilities. A snapshot is below:

[image]

A short introduction on how to use the color in the above mentioned [RGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) format can be found in *[1. Introduction to colors](https://texblog.org/2017/12/12/color-table-series-part-1-introduction-colortbl-package/#intro)*.